# Overwriting item in list using forloop

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, for-loop

I have this line of code that works:

```
results_percentage = results_percentage.set_index('date').dropna(how='all').resample('M').last()
```

When i try a forloop to do the same job, it doesn't work.  (I need to use y later):

```
list_a = [ (results_percentage, "results_percentage")]

for x, y in list_a :
    x = x.set_index('date').dropna(how='all').resample('M').last()
```

Comment: you need `drop_duplicates` for removing duplicates

Comment: I've amended the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're not updating the object, you're creating a new object and assigning it to a variable called `x`, not `list_a[0][0]`.

Use `inplace=True` to mutate the object

```py
x.set_index('date', inplace=True)
x.dropna(how='all', inplace=True)
```

Alternatively, you can assign back to the list

```py
for i, (x, y) in enumerate(list_a):
     list_a[i] = (x.set_index('date').dropna(how='all'), y)
```

Comment: How could I do inplace if I'm resampling? ```x.resample('W', inplace = True).last()```